# Почему не рисуется линия?

Tags: c++, winapi

```
Sleep(1000);
HWND window = FindWindow(NULL, L"Калькулятор");
if (window == NULL)return 0;

HDC dc = GetWindowDC(window);
if(dc==NULL)return 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    {
        SetPixel(dc, 5 + i, 5, RGB(255, 9, 9));
    }
```

В итоге ничего не происходит,хотя вроде хендл находится и GetWindowDC не возвращает 0.

Answer (score 4):

Почему же не рисуется? Отлично рисуется. Проверил.

Вот только увидеть это можно, если окно калькулятора ничем не перекрыто в момент запуска данной программы, и не сдвигается, иначе происходит перерисовка этого окна, и художества пропадают.

Для того, чтобы постоянно рисовать в чужом окне, нужно перехватить его оконную процедуру и подменить обработку сообщения `WM_PAINT`

Comment: странно,у меня даже 1 прорисовки не происходит,хотя ничего не перекрывает ничего

Comment: А зачем это вообще нужно?

Comment: Хороший вопрос,хотя бы,минимум,чтобы понимать как рисовать в окнах,но у меня даже с таким примером ничего не рисуется

Comment: В любом окне может и не получиться. Возможно, это зависит от тем (у меня не стоит темы). Для вывода в directx нужно endscene перехватывать и т.д. А вот в своём - рисуй в своё удовольствие.